# Flutter fractionally sized cells in Table

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible in flutter to render the table cells fractionally of the width and height of the parent widget. So with columns and rows this would be

```
   return SizedBox(
      width: 800,
      height: 600,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.yellow,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.orange,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Where each cell expands.

A Table in my opinion is more readable so I was wondering if it is possible with the Table widget.